# Layered Navigation Price Filter not working after update - Min/Max price in catalog_product_index_price is 0.000

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4, indexing, product-prices, catalog-product-price-index

Recently I upgrated magento to 2.4.2 and now I'm facing a problem with the Price Range filter by Mageplaza Layered Navigation.

I have managed to solve a previous problem of the price slider not appearing at all, but now there is another problem related to the product prices.

The filter displays only 0,00 - 0,00 as price range and when I use the slider to select a price range, the filtering ajax runs but it returns no results.

All the products are configurable with prices set to their configurations (which are simple products).

Searching for the cause of the error, I noticed that, in the rows about the configurable products, the columns price, min_price, max_price and price_tier of the catalog_product_index_price table are  set to 0.0000. All the other simple products have correct values. I tried changing manually the values of a configurable product and althought the price range displayed a max price (the one I set in tye configurable product), the filtering did not return any products.

So far I have tried

- Reindexing and clearing the cache
- Adding a product from the begining
- Checking the tables related to store configuration
- Increasing the innodb_buffer_pool_size and decreasing the batch size
- Changed the settings for the Layered Navigation Filter in Stores -> Configuration

So far nothing has worked.

Any ideas what could cause this problem or how it could be fixed?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE
After some research and testing I found out this problem occurs only with Configurable Products. Simple products are working fine. Also, the sort by Price is not working.

Comment: we are also facing almost similar problem here. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/372234/magento-2-4-5-p5-issue-with-indexers-causing-prices-to-drop-to-0-on-800k-skus

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I try to understood why table "catalog_product_index_price" on "price" column become zero on re-indexing.

Comment: The problem appears only in configurables products. The problem it is not the price filter, it is the price value on catalog_product_index_price table

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally managed to find a solution and fix the problem.
I don't know exactly what caused it and what action finally fixed it but the last thing I did was Invalidate all indexers from Admin -> System -> Index Management and run php bin/magento indexer:reindex.

I found this article that was really helpfull in finding a solution.
https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/index-in-magento-2/