# Magento 2.4.5-p5: Issue with Indexers Causing Prices to Drop to 0 on 800k SKUs

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, price, reindex, indexer

Hello Magento Community,

We're encountering a challenging issue with our **Magento 2.4.5-p5** project, **where product prices for approximately 7,000** out of our 800,000 SKUs (all configurable products) unexpectedly drop to 0 (both min and max prices). This problem seems to be related to our indexers, but we're unable to pinpoint the exact cause.

**Key Details:**

Magento Version: **2.4.5-p5**

Catalog Size: **~800k SKUs**,with the issue affecting around **7,000 configurable products**
Indexers Affected: EAV indexers are disabled for performance reasons.
Additional Modules: Utilizing **Amasty's Layered Navigation** module.

**Symptom Mitigation:** The issue is temporarily resolved by clearing all indexer tables and performing a full reindexing, coupled with a rebuild of Elasticsearch. However, the problem reappears without a clear pattern.
Despite extensive troubleshooting, including log reviews and configuration checks, the root cause remains elusive. We're unsure if the issue is directly related to Magento's indexing system, a conflict with the Amasty module, or another underlying factor.

**Questions for the Community:**

Has anyone faced a similar issue, especially with configurable products' prices being reset to 0?
Are there known conflicts with Amasty Layered Navigation that could affect indexing and product prices in this way?
Any recommendations on debugging techniques or specific configurations that might help identify the cause?
We appreciate any insights or experiences you can share. Identifying and resolving this issue is critical for us, and we're grateful for the community's support.

Thank you!